# How to align form at the center of the page using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter-bootstrap for styling. I have login the form and i am trying to get the form at the center of page. Most of the suggestions here on stackoverflow suggesting to put elements inside `container` class and thats what i am doing.
Requirement is The login form needs to have some background color and it needs to be at the center of the form. I have created a CSS class `.login-dialog` and applied that on `div` which is a wrapper around `form`

However there are issues:
-The whole row is getting background color
-The form and its controls are not aligning at the center
-There is lot of extra background on the right
(please see the picture below)

I can certainly fix this using `table` but i dont want to use any fix width solution. Can someone please help me on this

```
    <div class="container page-login">
        <div class="login-control-padding">
            <div class="row ng-hide" ng-show="model.errorMessage">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger ng-binding">
                        <strong>Error:</strong>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <span class="clientName ng-binding">Local Host Client</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div ng-show="model.loginUrl">
                    <div class="login-dialog">
                        <form name="form" class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength" role="form" action="/identity/login?signin=1111" method="post">
                            <input name="idsrv.xsrf" class="ng-isolate-scope" type="hidden" value="22222" token="model.antiForgery">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-1" for="username">Username</label>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input name="username" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" id="username" autofocus="" required="" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="Username" ng-model="model.username">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-1" for="password">Password</label>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input name="password" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-isolate-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength" id="password" required="" type="password" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password" ng-model="model.password" focus-if="model.username" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group" ng-show="model.allowRememberMe">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-1" for="rememberMe"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input name="rememberMe" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" ng-model="model.rememberMe">
                                    <span>Remember Me</span>
                                    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Login</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS class**

```
.login-dialog{
   background-color:rgb(40, 147, 194);
   border:solid;
   border-width:1px;
   border-radius:5px;
   border-color:rgb(28, 104, 137);    
   color:white;
   padding-top:10px;
  }


  .login-control-padding {
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `.login-dialog` is a block element ( stretches to full width ). So the blue color spans to full width.

But, In the form control you have added a class `.col-md-1` and `.col-md-3` classes. When make the form elements to span width of 4 (1+3) in 12 grids. so, remaining 8 grids left unused.

Now all you need to do is, add class `col-md-4 col-md-offset-4` in `login-dialog`. This will make form element to stay in center. Now change all `col-md-1` in label to `col-md-4` and `col-md-3` in form-control to `col-md-8`.

If you still confused, have a look at this, http://output.jsbin.com/lirilojeti

Hope it helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> -The whole row is getting background color

This is because the `.login-dialog` div does not have a specified bootstrap col class so it stretches to the width of the parent container, the `.row`.

> -The form and its controls are not aligning at the center

You'll need to use an offset class (`col-sm-offset-3` or the likes) to move the form more to the center

> -There is lot of extra background on the right

This should be fixed once your have the form width set correctly and centered how you want.

See my quick snippet:

```css
.login-dialog{
   background-color:rgb(40, 147, 194);
   border:solid;
   border-width:1px;
   border-radius:5px;
   border-color:rgb(28, 104, 137);    
   color:white;
   padding-top:10px;
  }


  .login-control-padding {
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container page-login">
        <div class="login-control-padding">
            <div class="row ng-hide" ng-show="model.errorMessage">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger ng-binding">
                        <strong>Error:</strong>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <span class="clientName ng-binding">Local Host Client</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div ng-show="model.loginUrl">
                    <div class="login-dialog col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <form name="form" class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength row" role="form" action="/identity/login?signin=1111" method="post">
                            <input name="idsrv.xsrf" class="ng-isolate-scope" type="hidden" value="22222" token="model.antiForgery">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-1" for="username">Username</label>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input name="username" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" id="username" autofocus="" required="" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="Username" ng-model="model.username">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-1" for="password">Password</label>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input name="password" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-isolate-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength" id="password" required="" type="password" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password" ng-model="model.password" focus-if="model.username" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group" ng-show="model.allowRememberMe">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-1" for="rememberMe"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input name="rememberMe" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" ng-model="model.rememberMe">
                                    <span>Remember Me</span>
                                    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Login</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: by adding `<div class="login-dialog col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">` align form to the center, however still The whole row is getting background color. because login-dialog is stretching..how to do I set the back ground just for that `cell`

Comment: basically I don't want the login-dialog to be spanned across only 6 columns